# Get one year ago date in db2

Tags: date, db2

I have a date in db2 like this: 1950-01-31. I wish to get a date correspondign to one year ago (i.e 1949-01-31).
I take a cue from :

```
current date + 1 YEAR 
current date + 3 YEARS + 2 MONTHS + 15 DAYS 
current time + 5 HOURS - 3 MINUTES + 10 SECONDS
```

I try:

```
select dateCol-1 year FROM table,
```

but it gives me 1950-01-30.
 Looks like it always deducts 1 from the day and not the year.
How can I get the date one year ago.

Comment: What client do you use to run your query? Is your database in the Oracle compatibility mode, by chance?

Comment: I use dbvisualizer which connects to a composite data virtual layer which connects to db2 in the background

Comment: what date you expect when date is 29.02.2004? 28Februar or 01March?

Comment: 29th feb --> 28th feb since both represent the last day of the month

Comment: I've no idea what is "composite data virtual layer", but there's a good chance that it is what's screwing up the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select date(days(dateCol)-(case when month(dateCol)=2 and day(dateCol)=29 then 366 else 365 end)) from table


db2 => values (date(days('28.02.2004')-(case when month(dateCol)=2 and day(dateCol)=29 then 366 else 365 end)))
>  2003-02-28
1 record(s) selected.

db2 => values (date(days('29.02.2004')-(case when month(dateCol)=2 and day(dateCol)=29 then 366 else 365 end)))
>  2003-02-28
1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Thnaks but i need a generic solution that works for february and leap years and things like that